How to get only plain text from a webpage
I am trying to access the contents of a webpage using urllib and bs4:
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2309.10034"
req = Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/7.0'})
webpage = str(urlopen(req).read())
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage)
text = soup.get_text()

However, this contains all kinds of non-ASCII characters like \n and \xc2 or \x89 or \subscript and so on. I want to remove all those characters and extract the plain text only. Is this possible and how can I do it?

The article contains many mathematical expressions etc which require Unicode characters. Removing them entirely seems disingenuous, and also will turn a name like Górski into Grski. As for the \subscript, probably just remove that particular phrase if you somehow can't cope with it.

Can I convert the sequences like \xc2 to actual characters?

I only need the text from the article, so the formulae are unnecessary.

\xc2 in isolation is not a Unicode character; it is the beginning of an UTF-8 sequence.

If you want to read that article with good focus, I recommend this Android app.

The changes I've made in the comments inside the code are important. Because I made the changes since I got a parser error initially.
Ensure lxml is installed. Install lxml if not installed before.
pip3 install lxml

Code:
import bs4

# Import re
import re

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# A function to remove non-ASCII characters
def clean_text(txt):
    
    # Remove non-ASCII characters
    txt = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', txt)
    
    return txt

url = "https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2309.10034"

# Update to the most common user agent(Mozilla/5.0)
req = Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

# Read webpage as bytes. (Remove converting into  string)
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

# Specify the Parser as lxml
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, features="lxml")

text = soup.get_text()
text = clean_text(text)

# Write to your preferred file.
with open('scrape_data.txt', 'w') as sd:
    sd.write(text)


A minimal fix is to remove the str() call and explicitly name which parser to use.
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2309.10034"
req = Request(url=url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/7.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, features="html.parser")
text = soup.get_text()

The str(urlopen(req).read()) you had would force a bytes string into a string, effectively hard-coding all the hex codes into the text. Now that you no longer do that, the text is already significantly cleaner (though it still contains text approximations of things that could be rendered in HTML, but not in plain text).

Here is a way to get the text only from that paper:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
soup = bs(requests.get('https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/2309.10034', headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
text_only = ' '.join([x.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for x in soup.select('p[class="ltx_p"]')])

print(text_only)

Result in terminal:
We present constraints on cosmological parameters using maps from the last Planck data release (PR4). In particular, we detail an upgraded version of the cosmic microwave background likelihood, HiLLiPoP , based on angular power spectra and relying on a physical modelling of the foreground residuals in the spectral domain. This new version of the likelihood retains a larger sky fraction (up to 75 %) and uses an extended multipole range. Using this likelihood, along with low- ℓ ℓ \ell measurements from LoLLiPoP , we derive constraints on Λ Λ \Lambda CDM parameters that are in good agreement with previous Planck 2018 results, but with 10 % to 20 % smaller uncertainties.
We demonstrate that [...]

You can look at further cleaning the text if you wish, using regex or python replace(). Documentation for requests is here, and for BeautifulSoup you can find it here.
Further edit:
A cleaner version of the text-only content can be extracted with:
text_only = ' '.join([' '.join(x.find_all(string=True, recursive=False)) for x in soup.select('p[class="ltx_p"]')])

